# Typo3 7.6 JS partially not working after migration

Tags: javascript, jquery, typo3, tablesorter

we migrated recently from Typo3 6.2 LTS to 7.6 LTS.
Now we have a problem with our js.

I do include the .js librarys as followed:

- jQuery 1.11
- tablesorter (version unknown)
- global.js (where I do call $(selector).tablesorter())

Now I do get an error which I didn't get on Typo3 6.2 LTS.
The error says "$(selector).tablesorter is not a function".

I checked my DOM tree / used js files and I could see that Typo3 7.6 includes jQuery 2.1.4.
Do you think this might be the reason for this feature?

Hopefully someone could already solve this problem. Thanks a lot!

Greetz, Paddaels

Comment: Does this error occur in the frontend or in the TYPO3 backend?

Answer (score 3):

I've seen this issue [many](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22582776/145346) [many](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30329828/145346) [times](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32019262/145346) (only linking the 3 I could quickly find).

Essentially, the first version of jQuery gets all the plugins bound to it (`$.fn`), so when the second copy of jQuery is loaded, the document ready function (located further down the DOM) is executing the second version that does not include any plugins.

Fix: remove the second copy of jQuery, or use `jQuery.noConflict()`. It's explained in more detail in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22582776/145346).

Comment: Well, I already have my code as they have for their solution. I've tried $.noConflict() but that didn't work. I've packed my code insode window.onload = function() { ... } but that didn't really helped. I have updated jquery and tablesorter but that didn't work. I don't get it... why does it keep telling me, that - even though I call $(..).tablesoter() inside $(function() {}) that $(...).tablesorter is not a function. I'll go crazy :(

Comment: Please share the code you are using, that would help us find the problem instead of guessing.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was requireJS.

With migrating from 6.2 LTS to 7.6 LTS Typo3 is now using requireJS.
jQuery, tablesorter (and some other librarys) are registering themselves as module.

We had to rewrite our code according to Typo3 7.6 docs.